# How can I adjust the server to run my PHP script quicker?

Tags: php, dedicated-server

I have a PHP script which runs on a loop for x amount of times.
The code is very minimal and performs checks.
Some loops will run within 1 second of each other and it varies.. some loops will run with up to 8 seconds delay.

How or what can I adjust/tweak on the server (or instruct the manager of my dedicated server) to reduce the time between loops to milliseconds (or as quick as possible) rather than 1 to 8 seconds?

Thank you!

**PHP code**

```
<style type="text/css">
#check { font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; margin-bottom: 40px; }
.red { color: #C00; }
.green { color: #060; }
</style>

<?php        date_default_timezone_set('Australia/Brisbane');   $var1 = "variable";     $var2 = 1;      $var3=="no";
                while ($var2 <= 50)     {

                        $sApiUrl = "https://www.apiurl.com/";

                        $aParams = Array(
                                    'uid'     => "user",   
                                    'pw'      => "key",    
                                    'command' => "command",     
                                    'sld'     => "main",        
                                    'tld'     => "ext");         


                        $oCurl = curl_init();
                        curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $sApiUrl);
                        curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                        curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $aParams);
                        curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                        curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                        $sResponse = curl_exec($oCurl);
                        curl_close($oCurl);


                        $oOutput = new SimpleXmlElement($sResponse);


                        foreach ($oOutput as $v1)
                          {  
                             foreach ($v1 as $v2)
                             { 
                                foreach ($v2 as $v3)
                                {
                                    foreach ($v3 as $v4=>$temp)
                                    {
                                         if($v4=="text")
                                            $var4 = $temp;
                                             if($var4=="true")
                                              {                                         
                                                    $aParams = Array(
                                                    'uid'     => "user",   
                                                    'pw'      => "key",  
                                                    'command' => "command",   
                                                    'sld'     => "main",       
                                                    'tld'     => "ext",
                                                    'dosomething' => "yes");    


                                                    $oCurl = curl_init();
                                                    curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_URL, $sApiUrl);
                                                    curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
                                                    curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $aParams);
                                                    curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
                                                    curl_setopt($oCurl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
                                                    $sResponse = curl_exec($oCurl);
                                                    curl_close($oCurl); 

                                                    $var3=="yes";   
                                              }                           
                                    }
                                }
                             }
                          }         $checktime = date('h:i:s A');                           echo "<div id=\"check\">$checktime, checked $var1<br>";         if ($var4=="true")          echo "<div class=\"green\"> $var4";         else            echo "<div class=\"red\"> $var4";
                if ($var3=="yes")           echo " and yes";    echo "</div></div>";        $var3=="no";    $loops++;   }        ?>
```

**Processor Information**

Processor #1 Vendor: GenuineIntel
Processor #1 Name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5405  @ 2.00GHz
Processor #1 speed: 1995.120 MHz
Processor #1 cache size: 6144 KB

Processor #2 Vendor: GenuineIntel
Processor #2 Name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5405  @ 2.00GHz
Processor #2 speed: 1995.120 MHz
Processor #2 cache size: 6144 KB

Processor #3 Vendor: GenuineIntel
Processor #3 Name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5405  @ 2.00GHz
Processor #3 speed: 1995.120 MHz
Processor #3 cache size: 6144 KB

Processor #4 Vendor: GenuineIntel
Processor #4 Name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5405  @ 2.00GHz
Processor #4 speed: 1995.120 MHz
Processor #4 cache size: 6144 KB

Processor #5 Vendor: GenuineIntel
Processor #5 Name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5405  @ 2.00GHz
Processor #5 speed: 1995.120 MHz
Processor #5 cache size: 6144 KB

Processor #6 Vendor: GenuineIntel
Processor #6 Name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5405  @ 2.00GHz
Processor #6 speed: 1995.120 MHz
Processor #6 cache size: 6144 KB

Processor #7 Vendor: GenuineIntel
Processor #7 Name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5405  @ 2.00GHz
Processor #7 speed: 1995.120 MHz
Processor #7 cache size: 6144 KB

Processor #8 Vendor: GenuineIntel
Processor #8 Name: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5405  @ 2.00GHz
Processor #8 speed: 1995.120 MHz
Processor #8 cache size: 6144 KB

**Memory Information**

Memory for crash kernel (0x0 to 0x0) notwithin permissible range
Memory: 8302344k/9175040k available (2176k kernel code, 80272k reserved, 901k data, 228k init, 7466304k highmem)

**System Information**

Linux server.myserver.com 2.6.18-194.17.1.el5PAE #1 SMP Wed Sep 29 13:31:51 EDT 2010 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

**Physical Disks**

SCSI device sda: 1952448512 512-byte hdwr sectors (999654 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: 03 00 00 08
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write back
SCSI device sda: 1952448512 512-byte hdwr sectors (999654 MB)
sda: Write Protect is off
sda: Mode Sense: 03 00 00 08
SCSI device sda: drive cache: write back
sd 0:1:0:0: Attached scsi disk sda
sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi removable disk sdb
sd 0:1:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg4 type 0
sd 4:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg7 type 0

**Current Memory Usage**

```
         total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
```

Mem:       8306672    7887632     419040          0     508076    6496876
-/+ buffers/cache:     882680    7423992
Swap:      4095992        428    4095564
Total:    12402664    7888060    4514604

**Current Disk Usage**

Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol00
                      898G  200G  653G  24% /
/dev/sda1              99M   19M   76M  20% /boot
none                  4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
/var/tmpMnt           4.0G  161M  3.6G   5% /tmp

Comment: Far more details needed.  Code examples and server setup info required.

Comment: Added server info, will add code shortly

Answer (score 1):

Do you use databases, emails, web services, or any other similar component? Generally, the performance of a PHP script is most dependent on these.

You can use a profiling tool like Xdebug to analyse your script and find the slowest areas of code. You can then optimise this code (e.g. inner loops) to improve performance.

Comment: thanks. The script does not connect to anything apart from an API. It passes values to the API and returns a code. Aside from Xdebug can anything else be done to improve performance?

Comment: @iCer: What is the API? By profiling, you can see if most of the time is spent in your PHP code or the API. There are many other options but I'd recommend profiling first.

Comment: it is a domain registrar API. Just downloaded Xdebug and have no idea what I am supposed to do with it :/

Answer (score 1):

I've not used this personally, but I suspect you need to look into using the curl_multi* stuff in PHP - this appears to allow you to perform multiple requests at once.

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Your bottleneck will almost certainly be making the HTTP connections serially. AFAIK the curl_multi_* functions will allow these to be performed in parallel.